# SSL certificate mismatch

Tags: bug, status-deferred, ssl

As I was researching a security related topic I visited the Security part of Stack Exchange for the first time (via google) and was sent to the `HTTPS` version of the site. Seeing the mixed content warning, I went straight to Meta to look for some answers - only to be greeted by a warm-hearted **certificate mismatch**.

[image: Certificate mismatch]

Now on the off-chance that attackers are truly intercepting my connection and stealing my information (in which case they just got access to my account - please forgive me for any future vandalism), it seems to me that it is a misconfiguration on the server. Furthermore, this would probably affect any site-specific Meta for an SE subdomain. Sites where `meta.` is the only subdomain, such as [Stack Overflow meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) and [Stack Exchange meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com) are of course not affected as they match the single wildcard.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a known issue. It has been discussed at length, it has to do with how wildcard certs work. Here's hoping that each additional report will eventually convince SE to find a solution (no matter how painful).

Comment: @AviD Ah, I just found [this blog post](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) by Nick Craver, but nothing on meta.security. I also can't seem to find anything more recent than 2013. Am I just looking in the wrong places?

Comment: yeah that's the one. meta.security is pretty much the same as meta.gaming or any other site here... I don't know if there is anything more recent, though they did re-confirm this sometime last year...